# protractor e2e typescript for mat-selection-list checkboxes - select all

Tags: typescript, xpath, css-selectors, protractor, angularjs-e2e

How do I check all checkboxes in this page using protractor ?

I tried to access the elements this way but doesn't seem to be working.

```
select = element(by.cssContainingText('mat-card-title', 'Classifications'))
    .all(by.css('mat-pseudo-checkbox'));
```

[image: page html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work because `mat-card-title` does not have any child elements. When chaining `element()` calls, it always only searches for child elements.

For selecting the correct elements, we have to take the parent `mat-card` and filter it by `by.cssContainingText()`.

After filtering we have to locate the `mat-pseudo-checkbox` elements and send a click to these underlying elements.

That can be achieved as follows:

```
// select correct element group
let wrapper = element.all(by.tagName('mat-card'))
  .filter(el => el.element(by.tagName('mat-card-title'))
  .getText()
  .then(text => {
    console.log('looking if\'', text, '\'contains Classifications');
    return text.indexOf('Classifications') > -1;
  }));

   wrapper.all(by.css('mat-card-content mat-selection-list mat-list-option .mat-list-item-content .mat-list-text'))
  .each(async el => await el.click());
```

#### Ressources

Protractor CheatSheet:

General Style guide for protractor => https://github.com/CarmenPopoviciu/protractor-styleguide

Cheat-sheet => https://gist.github.com/javierarques/0c4c817d6c77b0877fda

As your test suite grows, you should consider using the `Page Object Model` Pattern for your tests. We use it for our tests and it's a great pattern for separating test logic. => https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second one is my usecase. But Im getting an error on the last line of the second solution.`code` [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => void, thisArg?: any) => void) | ((call...' has no compatible call signatures.
(property) forEach: ((callbackfn: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => void, thisArg?: any) => void) | ((callbackfn: (value: ElementFinder, index: number, array: ElementFinder[]) => void, thisArg?: any) => void) `code`

Comment: I updated the code. I added a typing for the `filtered` variable in the `filter().then()` function.

Comment: Thanks for that. It fixed the error. But the code does not check the checkboxes.  No errors either.

Comment: This is how I clicked on one of the check boxes. Think its the div we should click on. How can we achieve that ? `code` const select = element(by.cssContainingText('mat-card-title', Classifications))
        .element(by.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "Coupon")]'));
      select.click();`code`

Comment: I looked a bit closer into the html and noticed a few things I made wrong. Please look at my updated answer. If that does not work we'll try your approach with `xpath`. But `xpath` should only be last resort.

Comment: That looked like the answer, but for some reason, its throwing error - No Element found using locator: by.cssContainingText('mat-card-title', 'Classifications')

Comment: I updated the answer again. Now the correct `mat-card-title` element is found by manually searching for text. I also added a `console.log()` which should help finding possible errors.

Comment: Thanks a ton Silvan. That did it. I am very new to protractor and angular and locating elements as it is evident. Could you point me towards some good resources  ?

Comment: @njosep I added some links in my answer.